# File uploading in flask and showing error message

Tags: python, file-upload

I'm implementing an application to process GPS data. In the application users can upload files and those files will be processed in server.

I need to validate the user uploaded file extension. But the problem is extensions can be change.

```
.17o, .11o, .12o, .13o, .14o, .15o, .23o, .54o
```

common patterns are

```
.*o, .*n, .*obs, .*nav, .nav, .obs
```

* is always a 2 Digit number

This is what I have tried

```
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(["*+'n'" , "*+'o'"])
```

How can I change the `ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS` to accept above mentioned common patterns.

I have used [flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/) for the upload file reference

I think I have to change this functions

```
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating an ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS_PTN to match these filenames. So, lets do like below:

```
import re

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS_PTN = re.compile(r"\d{2}(o|n|obs|nav)$") # matches 2 digits and any of o, n, obs, nav

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
        bool(ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS_PTN.match(filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()))
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. But in very rarely there are instances where users come across with `.nav` and `.obs`. Can you clarify how I can change `def allowed_file(filename):`  and `ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS_PTN`to validate `.obs` and `.nav` also.

Comment: @user9461345 the function `allowed_file` should be working for obs and nav extensions. We are checking for all the extentions you mentioned - `(o|n|obs|nav)`

Comment: some instances just .obs and .nav files can be upload without 2 digits

Comment: I think, then the pattern should be this - `ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS_PTN = re.compile(r"(\d{2}(o|n|obs|nav)$)|([\d{2}]*(obs|nav)$)")`. You may try and test if it works.

Comment: Wow. Worked like a charm!